# how to set width for CKEDITOR

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor

```js
async function TextEditor(element) {
  const newEditor = await ClassicEditor.create(element, {
    toolbar: [
      "heading",
      "bold",
      "italic",
      "bulletedList",
      "numberedList",
      "blockQuote",
    ],
  });

  return newEditor;
}
```

how to set width and height for CKEditor

```
async function TextEditor(element) {
```

const newEditor = await ClassicEditor.create(element, {
toolbar: [
"heading",
"bold",
"italic",
"bulletedList",
"numberedList",
"blockQuote",
],
});

return newEditor;
}

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not specify a CkEditor Version i'll assume v4.

the editor height is set to **200px** by default and width takes up **100%** of it's container.

supply the width or height config property when creating a new editor:

```
async function TextEditor(element) {
  const newEditor = await ClassicEditor.create(element, {
    toolbar: [
      "heading",
      "bold",
      "italic",
      "bulletedList",
      "numberedList",
      "blockQuote",
    ],
    width: 300,
    //resolves to 300px for fixed width
    // for percentage use '80%'
    height: 300,
  });

  return newEditor;
}
```

that should get you up and running as described in
[CkEditor Doc For Sizing](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/features/size.html)

Comment: @RobinChauhan what version of CkEditor Are you Using?